# pyautogui не работает на ломоной версии виндовс

Tags: python, pycharm, pyautogui

Я установил pyautogui, но pyCharm выдаёт ошибку.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\m\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pyautogui import gui
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'
```

Comment: Вы в PyCharm скорее всего используете виртуальную среду, пакеты надо в ней ставить. Либо не пользоваться виртуальной средой.